# BizTalk AS2 - Why field is promoted as AS2ToInternal instead of AS2To

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2016

Why would the promoted field name be called AS2ToInternal instead of AS2To as we are expecting?   Pipeline used is AS2Receive on a Sync Port.

We have a SendPort setup to filter on the promoted field: AS2IntAS.AS2To, and since that value is missing, we are get a routing failure.

[image]

When I look in the InboundHttpHeaders value, everything looks correct, for example:

```
AS2-Version: 1.2
AS2-To: Zxxxx
AS2-From: 1xxxx
```

Comment: I wrote a pipeline to fix, to re-promote AS2To from AS2ToInternal, but no idea why I had to do this.  In testing it, I found that I had to put it after the AS2 Disassembler stage.  Everything was fine in the Decode stage.

Comment: @NealWatlters we are facing the same issue. Could you share the pipeline with us?

Comment: @CoroveiAndrei - This will get you started.  You will still have to know how to build, compile, and make a pipeline from it. http://mylifeismymessage.net/biztalk-pipeline-to-fix-promotion-as2tointernal-vs-as2to/

Comment: Thank you for the code - we did write our own code and it looked very similar to yours. Where did you put this pipeline component? On the validation placeholder in the receive pipeline?

Comment: @CoroveiAndrei I think it was the second or last phase.  If I remember, first one didn't work.  Don't have access to everything now.

Comment: Please note that the solution will break the generation of MDN - there is an error related to the value AS2To which is not found. I suppose the MDN generation also tries to promote that value? Or it expects the context values in a certain order and by promoting the AS2To property the order is not preserved.